# how to change the li class

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to change the class for an li

this is what I have but its not working:

```
var selectorsList = $('.myselectorClass').find('li');
$(selectorsList).each(function(i,k){
    $(k).addClass('selected');
});
```

here is the html:

```
<div class="myselectorClass" data-multiselect="1" data-type="zusize" id=zusize>
    <ol>
        <li class=""  >2T</li>
        <li class="" >3T</li>
    </ol>                   
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you define 'not working' a little more throughly?

Comment: You should wrap your code inside `jQuery(function($){ /* your-code */ })`

Comment: The code you have submitted doesn't contain any errors and run perfectly. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: li doesnt get selected class as it should

Comment: Also, you should use `$(this)` when you're inside the element I think

Answer (score 1):

it is as simple as - there is no need to iterate using `each`, jQuery will do it for you

```
$('.myselectorClass').find('li').addClass('selected');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aLj3Z/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(selectorsList).each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

This works.  Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axl163/z5HNS/1/).

Comment: Is there a point to `i` or `k` in the callback as they are not being used?

Comment: Well, we may only be looking at a portion of the code.  Maybe they are being used.

Comment: so that doesnt work still. I dont get the class being selected

Comment: @AllenLiu You didn't fix anything, it works with k too.
http://jsfiddle.net/z5HNS/2/ . His issue must lie somewhere else.